# GAS Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, open-with

this is question related to google apps script and Google Drive.

Is there any way to construct a URL for a file that causes opening that file in desktop application?
I'm basically asking whether it is possible to access "Open With" application list programmatically and pick up one from listed applications.

Now, when I get the URL, it causes opening another screen where I need to pickup an application and only then it starts opening. I would like to skip that step and open the file directly in a given desktop application.

Thank you!
Petr

Comment: The user interface only appears when a user opens a google application.  When a script opens up an application it only get's opened on the server

Comment: Apps Script is a web-based platform that runs your script on Google's server. It is not possible to open a local/desktop application using apps script. As you mentioned, the closest solution is to open your drive file on a new tab using apps script and select the application under `open with` button to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

"Open Width" requires having Google Drive for Desktop installed, having installed a Chrome extension and using Chrome.

Considering the above, since Google Apps Script server side code hasn't access to user environment it's not possible to

> "Open With" application list programmatically and pick up one from listed applications.